# How can I override internal style or button in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-styles, firebaseui

I would like override the Google Login button showed in Firebase UI for Android.

In FirebaseUI-Android/auth/src/main/res/values/styles.xml there is

```
 <style name="FirebaseUI.Button.AccountChooser.GoogleButton">
    <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/logo_googleg_color_18dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/idp_button_background_google</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#757575</item>
  </style>
```

and in FirebaseUI-Android/auth/src/main/res/layout/idp_button_google.xml is:

```
 <Button
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   style="@style/FirebaseUI.Button.AccountChooser.GoogleButton"
   android:text="@string/sign_in_with_google"
   android:id="@+id/google_button"
 />
```

I would like to change the background color of GoogleButton in my app, I was thinking to override the style or change by code the background in some way.

Any suggestion?

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android